# iPhone - detect first time launch with phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am trying to detect the first time launch of a newly installed application and display a license agreement for the application.  The user must accept the lincense or leave the application..

Does anyone know how I can do this using Phonegap?  I have searched through the topics but I cant seem to find this anywhere.

Thank You

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use local storage to keep track of app launch counts.

```
var applaunchCount = window.localStorage.getItem('launchCount');

//Check if it already exists or not
if(applaunchCount){
   //This is a second time launch, and count = applaunchCount
}else{
  //Local storage is not set, hence first time launch. set the local storage item
  window.localStorage.setItem('launchCount',1);

  //Do the other stuff related to first time launch
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info...  I am not very technical, so can this be done with javascript and a custom message shown on first launch?..  Even if this is a <div> element that only shows on the first launch it would be perfect

Comment: Yeah.. you can show the custom message in the else part(which is the case for first launch)

Answer (score 1):

Now iOS may clear localStorage, so you cannot count on it being persistent.

For truly persistent storage, one option would be the file system plugin

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file

Please note that if your APP is uninstalled, your persistent file would most likely be removed also. Which is probably fine for this application.