# Execute script when install and uninstall cordova app using ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

For Some years I'm working with cordova and less than 1 year with ionic.

I'm looking for the way to run a JavaScript function when the app is being installed and when is being uninstalled.

I have done many searches but have not found anything about it, someone has an idea, at least an approximation to serve as a starting point?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check these posts:

- [Detect uninstall event in phonegap app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317635/detect-uninstall-event-in-phonegap-app)
- [iPhone - detect first time launch with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988264/iphone-detect-first-time-launch-with-phonegap)

However I think it's really difficult to raise an "uninstall event" (eventually by a Cordova plugin) which can be listened by your JS code.

Instead it's easier to check first time the app is launched using localStorage as suggestend in the 2nd post.