# Is there an event in Cordova for when the app is about to be uninstalled or updated?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I need your help. We are currently using Ionic and Cordova to build a mobile app. With iOS devices, we use UDID when registering the device, but the interesting part is the UDID changes every time the app gets uninstalled or updated, thus makes a registration abandoned. I need your help guys to figure out how we can unregister a device before it gets uninstalled or updated. Is there an event I can hook into to atleast call our unregister API endpoint before the UDID gets refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heads up, you cannot know when your cordova app is uninstalled. But please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721756/execute-script-when-install-and-uninstall-cordova-app-using-ionic) out for some helpful information.